Get cell value using Graph API v6.x is not displaying the value in Java SDK
While fetching the get cell value from the worksheet, no value is return in Java SD of MS Graph API:
graphClient.drives().byDriveId(driveId).items().byDriveItemId(driveItemId)
        .workbook().worksheets().byWorkbookWorksheetId(sheetId).cellWithRowWithColumn(1, 1).get().getValues();

Screenshot of output from Java SDK
When I tried with the postman and graph explorer for the same, there the value is displaying correctly
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/driveID/items/driveItemID/workbook/worksheets/sheetID/cell(row=1,column=1)

Postman Output
Graph Explorer Output

Given it is working on Graph Explorer and not in your code, it is likely something with your code that needs to be fixed. One reason for this is likely that the method returns a JsonElement object and you need to return the actual value from it. Can you test using getValue() instead to see if the actual value is returned directly. Could be:
String value = graphClient.drives().byDriveId(driveId).items().byDriveItemId(driveItemId)
.workbook().worksheets().byWorkbookWorksheetId(sheetId).cellWithRowWithColumn(1, 1).get().getValue();
System.out.println("Cell value: " + value);

I tried this way also, but there is no json value in the response
